# How to use an index with MongoCollection.Update()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am writing a method that updates a single document in a very large `MongoCollection`, 
and I have an index that I want the `MongoCollection.Update()` call to use to drastically reduce lookup time, 
but I can't seem to find anything like `MongoCursor.SetHint(string indexName)`.

Is using an index on an update operation possible?  
If so, how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you already have indexed your collection, update will be using the CORRECT index right away. There is no point to provide hint (in fact you [can't hint with update](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599)).

[Hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) is only for debugging and testing purposes. Mongo is in most cases smart enough to automatically decide which index (if you have many of them) should be used in a particular query and it reviews its strategy from time to time.

So short answer - do nothing. If you have an index and it is useful, it will be automatically used on find, update, delete, findOne.

If you want to see if it is used - take the part of the query which searches for something and run it through find with [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/).

**Example for hellboy.** This is just an example and in real life it can be more complex.
So you have a collection with docs like this `{a : int, b : timestamp}`. You have 2 indexes: one is on `a`, another is on `b`. So right now you need to do a query like a > 5 and b is after 2014. For some reason it uses index `a`, which does not give you the faster time (may be because you have 1000 elements and most of them are bigger than 5  and only 10 are > 2004 ). SO you decided to hint it to use `b` index. Cool it works much faster now. But your collection changes and right now you are in 2020 year and most of your documents have b bigger than 2014. So right now your index `b` is not doing so much work. But mongo still uses it, because you told so.

Comment: "Mongo is smart enough to automatically decide which index" is not always right. If you have many composite indexes, which look similar, then mongo sometimes goes wrong and do not use the right index or no index at all. I have seen this behavior in my load testing. I always use hint while using composite index to guarantee that mongo hits the index.

Comment: @hellboy But here is a problem that can appear with your hint. There are two possible candidates for using an index. And currently (based on the documents in you database it makes sense to use index1). You hinted to use index1 and mongo is using it. But with time (adding new docs and modifying old) index2 became much nicer. But mongo will not use it. So there is a trade off. And based on the question - OP is not really sure that index will be used in update operation.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am not sure I am getting you. Whatever attributes you are filtering with is not changing based on the document value. The index depends only on the attributes being used for filter. So, not sure I have understood how change in the value will influence the index choice.

Comment: @hellboy here is example for you (edited the question). This is theoretically just to show what can go wrong with hint and why you should be careful with it.

Comment: I ignored that possibility. I guess hint may be good or may not be good,  it all depends on the queries that we run and the kind of indexes that we have.  In the example that you posted if I had composite index wit a and b,  then the query would have hit that.

Comment: @hellboy even mongodb is telling to use it for testing. (Which I wrote in answer).

Comment: There are many times where the index Mongo chooses to use is not the optimal index, and even the results from a .explain() will say the query will use a different plan than the one that Mongo actually uses.  Using .hint() with queries is sometimes necessary, especially when the plan cache is stale.

Comment: @MatthewAntolovich and you are planning to leave hint in your production system? What will you do in a day when the statistics about your underlying data will change (read my example carefully)? Will you be rebuilding binaries every day to make sure your hint will stay up-to-date constantly. Yes, sometimes databases do not use the optimal index, but in most cases they are, and even when they do not chose the right index right away, they will adjust with time. Do not think that you are smarter than the whole optimization team behind the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can create `index` according to your `query` section of update command.

For example if you have this collection, named `data`:

```
> db.data.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5334908bd7f87918dae92eaf"), "name" : "omid" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5334943fd7f87918dae92eb0"), "name" : "ali" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53349478d7f87918dae92eb1"), "name" : "reza" }
```

and if you do this update query:

```
> db.data.update(query={name:'ali'}, update={name: 'Ali'})
```

without any defined index, the number of scanned document is  `2`:

```
"nscanned" : 2,
```

But if you define an index, according to your `query`, here for `name` field:

```
db.data.ensureIndex({name:1})
```

Now if you update it again:

```
> db.data.update(query={name:'Ali'}, update={name: 'ALI'})
```

Mongodb use your index for doing update, and number of scanned document is `1`:

```
"nscanned" : 1,
```

But if you want to `hint` for update, you can hint it for your query:

```
# Assume that the index and field of it exists.
> var cursor = db.data.find({name:'ALI'}).hint({family:1})
```

Then use it in your update query:

```
> db.data.update(query=cursor, update={name: 'ALI'})
```

Comment: I already have the index, and I have ensured its existence.  I'm asking if there's a way to explicitly tell the update query to use one specific index (and if so, how), or will Mongo just infer what index to use by the parameters of the query?

Comment: You can't hint the update directly while calling the update api. In most cases, mongo will use the index properly. It might miss indexes rarely due to a bug. I have seen this bug in fetch, not sure if this happens in update as well. I have observed this issue only when you have many composite indexes which use similar attributes in different combination. Update should work most times without having to hint